# My toolbar stay Simplified Chinese although other areas has been English

Tags: front-end

I use mma 11.3 in English.

Once I changed the Language settings. English->Simplified Chinese

But when I switch the setting back, I find the toolbar in the main windows 
remains S Ch.

Screen Shots is following

Used to be:

[image]

Now
[image]

[image]

How can I make everywhere Eng?

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag unless other people have confirmed that the behavior you observed is a bug.

Comment: @J.M. I got it.

Comment: For the change to take effect you need to quit and restart Mathematica. Did you?

Comment: @BobHanlon I even reinstalled the mma, but nothing worked.